# IOAuthCredentials which namespace contains this

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to create MVC4 app on VS2012, with angulajs and linqtoTwitter package installed from PM.

I do not find IOAuthCredentials which is expected in the LinqToTwiter N.S

Comment: You could have [Googled it](https://github.com/nuvi/linqtotwitter/blob/master/LinqToTwitterAg/OAuth/IOAuthCredentials.cs)? If you've included the libraries, didn't IntelliSense offer to auto-import the namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem, with the exact same sample project.  Seems that they changed things so it no longer works as it previously did.
You might want to check out this discussion to get some ideas on how to change the code.
https://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/discussions/532368

Unfortunately, if you're like me and trying to learn something, having to rework the samples just adds a fun level of difficulty :(